# How to record phone call on iPhone with Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

How can I record a phone call (both caller and callee voices) from Xamarin.Forms for iOS devices?

There are a dozen of apps for this in the Android store however I've read in other posts that for iPhones it is not possible, because of the sandboxed nature of Apple's apps. 
Is it possible ?

Comment: You have answered your own question!

Comment: I don't think so. Everything I've read is a little bit outdated, there may be changes in the current/future moment.

Comment: Given Apple's commitment to privacy, this is not an ability that you would expect them to ever add. If you find old information that is privacy related you can generally assume that the current state is the same or more restricted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible with any of the public API(s) provided to us by Apple.